# Cannot create user at runtime with Query with parameters

Tags: interbase, mbcs

I am using C++ Builder 10.2.3 (Rad Studio Tokyo 10.2.3) with Interbase 2017
I need to create users at runtime for my users registration.
If I create the Query at runtime, in that case there is no parameter, it works. But this creates problems with MBCS characters I will explain later.
If I create the Query at design-time with parameters and try to set the parameters at runtime. I am getting the error message below:

```
[Application: ]
[Error] -104 335544569 Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 2, char 14
 ?
```

The query I am using is below:

```
CREATE USER myuser 
SET PASSWORD :mypass, 
FIRST NAME :myfirstname, 
LAST NAME :myname;
```

I replace the first line of the Query at runtime, so there is no character. And after all, Interbase cannot handle MBCS characters in USERNAME.
I need to use a Query with parameters because my application handles multi-bytes characters (MBCS), like Chinese and Japanese.  And this is the only option to be sure of a proper conversion to UTF8 in Interbase. Because if the conversion of MBCS characters is not done, I cannot backup and restore my database. When I try to restore with MBCS characters in First and last name, I am getting an error message that Interbase cannot transliterate between character sets.

Base on the error message, it appears to me that it does not recognize the Query parameters.
I tried with both "TIBQuery" and "TIBSQL". Same issue. Impossible to use also Store procedures. Does not recognize the create word.
So, how to fix that ?